# How to firebase.push in Clojurescript? Is my data correct?

Tags: javascript, firebase, clojurescript

I'm am trying to `.push` some data to my Firebase but I'm getting this error in my Chrome console:

> Uncaught Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument  contains an invalid key (cljs$lang$protocol_mask$partition0$) in property 'arr.0'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

Here's my code:

```
fb (js/Firebase. "https://example.firebaseio.com/example-listings")

(def app-state (atom {"post" { :first_name "Billy"
                               :last_name "Bob"
                               :location "CA"
                               :email "bob@aol.com"
                               :website "www.pwt.com"
                          }}))

(def postData (get-in @app-state ["post"]))
(.push fb postData)
```

I also tried replacing the keys with strings `:first_name` with `"first_name"`. I understand Clojure's data structures are a bit different from JavaScript. Is it the case that Firebase isn't liking my Clojure map?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firebase expects a JavaScript object to its API calls. You are passing it a Clojure data structure (in this case a map). You have to convert your Clojure data structure to a JavaScript object before passing it to the Firebase function.

So instead of:

```
(.push fb postData)
```

you need to do:

```
(.push fb (clj->js postData))
```